# get_users with Serialized Custom Meta Value

Tags: meta-query, user-meta, users

I'm attempting to use `get_users` to select users with only a certain meta value.  In this case the meta key is `extraInfo` but the the values are in a serialized array.  Can I pull users out like this?  This is what I've been trying with no luck:

```
$meta_key = 'extraInfo[zip]';
$meta_value = $zip;
$query    = get_users('meta_key='.$meta_key.'&meta_value='.$meta_value);
```

Comment: There's no way to do this without writing the SQL yourself. You're better off saving data in individual keys if you need to query on it, much more efficient.

Comment: I agree.  I'll need to make this update on almost 7000 users.

Comment: I suggest writing a script to get users, load their meta, then save it out to individual keys. You can use offset and number arguments to do it in batches so you don't crush your server.

Comment: Thanks.  Thats exactly what I need to do.  I'll post my solution when I have a working script.  I've seen the same thing accomplished here on Stack Exchange but with custom post types.  It will be similar.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, this can't be done with any efficiency.  The best thing to do is pull the data out of the serialized array and save each as their own key/value pair in the `wp_usermeta` table.  My key was `extraInfo` and the values I needed were serialized in the value.  This is the script I've used to create new keys and values from the data automatically.  The echoing was just used for some on screen feedback and isn't necessary.  If you have a lot of users, you might want to use `number` and `offest` in the `get_users` query.  Hope this helps someone.

```
<?php

$users = get_users( 'number=10' );
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $extras = unserialize(get_the_author_meta( "extraInfo", $user->ID ));
    foreach ($extras as $key=> $value) {
        echo '<p>' . $key . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, $key, $value);
    }
    echo '<p>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</p>';
    echo '<hr>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php
            /**
             * are you sure that your meta value is ok
             */
            $meta_key = 'extraInfo[zip]';
            $meta_value = $zip;
            $query    = get_users(
            array(
                'meta_key' => $meta_key,
                'meta_value' => $meta_value
            ));
```

Comment: Yes I'm sure the value is good.  It's definitely an issue with the meta values being serialized.  Not sure there is way to get them without updating the whole save routine and pulling them out of the serialized array.